# Spring, Oauth2: authentication details lost after refreshing the token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have two Spring applications: an *Authentication Service* and a *Business Service*.

When a webservice user authenticates at the *Authentication Service*, he gets an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`. He can refresh his `access_token` by sending the `refresh_token` to the service. The service implements `AuthenticationProvider`, there the details of the authentication are set:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException { 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken newAuthentication = ...;
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> detailsMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) authentication.getDetails();
    detailsMap.put(...);
    newAuthentication.setDetails(detailsMap);
    return newAuthentication;
}
```

The *Business Service* is secured by `Oauth2`. Its controller contains

```
@Secured({ SOME_ROLE })
@RequestMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> detailsMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) authentication
            .getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
```

If the webservice user authenticates at the *Authentication Service* and calls the *Business Service*, `detailsMap` will contain the information set in `authenticate()`. But if he refreshes the token and calls the *Business Service* again, `detailsMap` will be `null`.

I want the `detailsMap` to be preserved after the token has been refreshed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround we do not use the `details` anymore, but save their data into the `UserDetails` implementation `UserDetailsImplementation`.

In the method `Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)` of the `AuthenticationProvider` implementation we return a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` whose `principal` is set to `UserDetailsImplementation`. This `UserDetailsImplementation` is also returned in the `UserDetailsService` implementation which is called at the refreshing of the token.

In the *Business Service* we can access the desired data by

```
((UserDetailsImplementation) authentication.getPrincipal()).getDesiredData();
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. However, I dont want to refresh the token but I want to set details in the token when the user logs in. But OAuth2Authentication#setDetails apparently is doing nothing and the details that I set are being overwritten. Could you help?

Comment: @PranjalGore: please open a new question.